# SQL, Update where id, Code is correct no errors but its not updating

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

I have a database.

I like to update my table "Personen", using the input from a **textbox**.
When I click a **button**, It says it is updated. But it is not updated when I query the database.

Here is my code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlIns = @"UPDATE Personen SET Voornaam=@VN, Tussenvoegsel=@TN, Achternaam=@AN WHERE (ID=@ID) ;";

        //Maak commando object
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlIns, Connectie);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxVerwijderen.Text));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VN", Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TN", Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AN", Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text));
        Connectie.Close();
        try
        {
            //Open de connectie
            Connectie.Open();
            //Voer commando uit
            command.ExecuteReader();
            Connectie.Close();
            //Meldingen succes op het scherm
            LabelSucces.Text = "Persoon is succesvol Geupdate " + sqlIns;
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, "Exception details");
        }
        finally
        {
            //Sluiten van de connectie
            Connectie.Close();
        }
    }
```

Greetings.
Alex

Comment: Try checking the ID parameter, maybe you are NOT passing a correct value, also check what count `ExecuteNonQuery()` is returning

Comment: Are you sure there is a row which fulfills (ID=@ID)?

Answer (score 0):

Use
 **`command.ExecuteNonQuery();`**
Inplace of **`command.ExecuteReader();`**

Use Query like this

```
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxVerwijderen.Text));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("VN", Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("TN", Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AN", Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text));
```

Comment: What you are passing in connection string? are you getting any exception?

Comment: OleDbConnection Connectie = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\visual_studio1\test.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");

That is working 100%,
Nope i don't get any exceptions at all.

Comment: Yes it's updating now, i have the problem that when i update it, the ID is going on the place of Voornaam and not The ID i wanted to update with the new value. U also can help my with that?

Comment: ok then accept this answer then i also had updated my ans in new way too

Comment: If you get it working this way, try to find what was wrong with your first approach anyway. I would strongly discourage to just take a string from a Textbox, you may look up SQL Injection. The original parameter based approach was much better in this sense.

Comment: @MartinK. I apology for my ans, i had updated it too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connectie.Close();
```

looks like this is the problem. remove it and try open connection in start and close in end. do not do anything between.